# How to remove function name prefix from winston logger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

When logging with winston, it adds the level prefix to every line:

```js
const winston = require('winston');
const logger = new (winston.Logger)();

logger.info('line 1'); 
logger.debug('line 2');

/*
output:
info: line 1
debug: line 2
*/
```

It there a way to use the level functions without them outputting the prefix?